# Recovering partitions from a disk image

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, gparted

I've done this before and it worked; now I have a problem when recovering
a Win10 partition from a disk image.

Steps taken:

1. Booted gparted USB image; working (bootable) system:

[image: gparted working setup]

2. Mounted external drive:

   mkdir ExternalDriveMount
   mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 ./ExternalDriveMount
   cd ExternalDriveMount
   mkdir Disk_C_Backup
3. Moved win 10 partition to drive (not sure if correct):

   dd if=/dev/nvme0n1 of=./Disk_C_Backup/C_backup.dd bs=16M status=progress
4. Leave over night
5. Image file seems alright (size-wise)
6. Copying to new Win10 machine (both have a 1TB ssd Win10 partition (same partition layout)) after mounting (external) drive:

   dd if=./Disk_C_Backup/C_backup.dd of=/dev/nvme0n1 bs=16M status=progress
7. After completion I notice that the image hasn't been broken up into partitions (partition layout is different than that of the working device):

[image: non-working setup]

What exactly is the relationship between

```
/dev/nvme0n1
```

and it's partitions:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p2
/dev/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p4
```

At a glance, the sum of sizes of each equals the size of nvme0n1.

Last time I moved an image file into /dev/nvme0n1 the resulting drive was bootable.

Comment: Removing others...

Comment: @K7AAY It looks like the OS partition is a "data" partition in that it does not handle boot operations directly. I'm copying each partition one by one

Comment: With gpt best not to use dd on partitions. Use other tools that recognize gpt. Gpt uses GUIDs that must match primary & backup partition tables, if they get out of sync you then have major issues.

Answer (score 0):

/dev/nvme0n1 is the total capacity of the raw physical [NVMe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVM_Express) drive.

/dev/nvme0n1p1 is the [EFI partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition) required to boot.

/dev/nvme0n1p2 is the [Microsoft Reserved Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition), an alternative data storage space for such software components which previously may have used hidden sectors on MBR formatted disks. Microsoft expects an MSR to be present on every GPT disk. Some chunks of the MSR partition may also be used for remapping damaged sectors by software, or used as a temporary mirror for critical operations on the core GPT structure or in emergency for fast writing of the internal disk cache memory in case of power failure, and for fast recovery when powering up the system.

/dev/nvme0n1p3 is your Windows 10 system and data partition. That's where all your content is.

/dev/nvme0n1p4 is a hidden partition used exclusively for Windows recovery.  Sometimes manufacturers will add a second hidden partition with their own recovery software as well.

Suggest you back up a partition at a time, then restore them one partition at a time, instead of the entire drive, since SSDs may look like they're the same size, but there are minor variations in manufacture which may result in small variations in size. I like to leave 1MB of empty space between partitions, and if anything must be shrunk on restoration, downsize /dev/nvme0n1p3. A different tool may be required.

Comment: /dev/nvm0n1 is the raw (physical) drive. I can't come all partitions (nvm0n1 included) on the backup drive since there wouldn't be enough space to move them back (nvm0n1 is ~930 GB). Last time I did this I remember being no problems moving the cloned image back onto the drive).